# The study of the properties of the solution of Heat equation.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations

I am studying the following basic heat equation. (All notations follows Evans book)
\begin{align}
u_t -\Delta u =0 &\text{ in }\mathbb R^2\times(0,\infty)\\
u=u_0 &\text{ on }\mathbb R^2\times\{t=0\}
\end{align}
i.e., the Cauchy problem. Here we assume $u_0\in C_c^\infty(\mathbb R^2)$ and $u_0$ is non-negative.

Let $u(x,t)$ denote the standard solution so that 
$$
u(x,t):=\frac{1}{4\pi t}\int_{\mathbb R^2}e^{-\frac{|x-y|^2}{4t}}u_0(y)dy \tag 1
$$

Now given a function $a(x)\in C_c^\infty(\mathbb R^2)$ so that 
$$
\int_{\mathbb R^2}a(x)\,dx=0,\,\,\int_{\mathbb R^2}a(x)u_0(x)\,dx=C = \int_{\mathbb R^2}(a(x))^2dx,
$$
where $C>0$ is a constant. (Note the above equation does not mean $u_0=a$)

---

Now I need to study the following equation:
$$
f(t):=\int_{\mathbb R^2} [u(x,t)-u_0(x)]\cdot\partial_t u(x,t)\,dx - \int_{\mathbb R^2} \partial_tu(x,t)\cdot a(x)\,dx. \tag 2
$$
Notice that 
$$f(t) = \frac{d}{dt} \frac{1}{2}\int (u(x,t)-u_0+a)^2dx$$

My questions:

1. Assume that there exist $t_0>0$ so that $f(t_0)=0$. Prove that for all $0<t<t_0$, $f(t)<0$; and for all $t>t_0$, $f(t)>0$. And I expect $f(t)\to 0$ as $t\to\infty$.
2. Give a condition on $u_0$ so that there exists such $t_0>0$. (the condition can not be $u_0$ is a constant.)

---

What I tried so far is put $(1)$ into $(2)$ and see what's going on. But so far I got nothing... I suspect 
$$
0\leq \int_{\mathbb R^2}a(x)u(x,t_2)\,dx\leq \int_{\mathbb R^2}a(x)u(x,t_1)\,dx\leq \int_{\mathbb R^2}a(x)u_0(x)\,dx
$$
for $0<t_1<t_2$ but I can not prove it.

Any help is really welcome!

Comment: Is Q1 equivalent to 'f is nondecreasing' ?

Comment: @BCLC  not exactly. What I want is $f(t)<0$ as $t<t_0$, $f(t)>0$ as $t>t_0$; so the graph of $f(t)$ looks like a spoon.

Comment: @BCLC: I restated the problem. Thanks for pointing out!

Comment: tankonetoone, sooooo w/o your edit, Q1 is equivalent to 'f is nondecreasing' ?

Comment: @BCLC: Yes. But I actually expect $f$ decreasing first and than increasing

Comment: Also is the std solution really over $\mathbb R^2$ ?

Comment: @BCLC I think yes. This is what I got from Evans

Comment: But you're integrating w/rt 1 variable?

Comment: @BCLC: Yes, $t$ is the time variable, and $x$ is the space variable.

Comment: so y is a vector $y=[x,t]$ or something?

Comment: no, for a fixed $x$, $y$ is the space variable you are integrating with.

Comment: Edited. Revert if you disagree. Also, missing some [square roots](https://upload.wikimedia.org/math/9/a/b/9ab5dbc250c28a3b8b0229fecde6a4cb.png)?

Comment: Oh wait $x, y \in \mathbb R^2$?

Comment: Also, I think $\frac{t_1}{t_2} e^{-a(\frac{t_2 - t_1}{t_1t_2})} \ge 0$. If so, then if $t_1 < t_2$, then I think $u(x,t_2) \ge u(x, t_1)$ for $a := \frac{-|x-y|^2}{4}$

Comment: @BCLC: Thx for your editing. But I think you forgot to consider that there is a $t$ in front of integration also...

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: @BCLC: sorry I confused. where are you get this equation? i.e., $\frac{t_1}{t_2}e^{-a(\frac{t_2-t_1}{t_1t_2})}$?

Comment: I compared $u(x,t_2)$ and $u(x,t_1)$. Assuming I did the comparing right, I think $u(x,t_2) \ge u(x,t_1)$ for $t_1 < t_2$

Comment: @BCLC：when you compare, I think you forgot the integration part...

Comment: Work backwards :P $\int_E f dx \le \int_E g dx$ if $f \le g$